# Javascript regex optional character at any position and bordered by specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I need to find and change a given string wherever it occurs within a document. There are two conditions which I can handle separately but can't get to work together.

1. Words are sometimes broken across lines with `-\n` and those should always be matched.
2. The string should only be matched if it is bordered by a character which is not alphanumeric nor a hyphen.

Suppose I want to wrap the matched text with a `<stuff>` tag. For the first I have the following which feels ugly but works. I insert an optional `-\n` group between each character in every word.

```
function createMask(term){
    var words = term.split(' ');
    new_words = [];
    for(i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        var word = words[i].split('').join('(\\-\\n)?');
        new_words.push(word);
    }
  var mask = new_words.join('\\s'); \\Any space is ok here.
  return mask;
}
var doc = 'This is sand, and rand,\nand something else a-\nn-\nd ';
var mask = createMask('and');
var newDoc = doc.replace(RegExp(mask, 'ig'), '<stuff>$&</stuff>');
```

This matches the last 'and' but also the ones within 'sand' and 'rand'.

For the second I can do the following

```
function createMask(term){
  var mask = '([^a-zA-Z0-9-])(' + term + ')([^a-zA-Z0-9-])';
  return mask;
}
var doc = 'This is sand, and rand,\nand something else a-\nn-\nd ';
var mask = createMask('and');
var newDoc = doc.replace(RegExp(mask, 'ig'), '$1<stuff>$2</stuff>$3');
```

Combining the expressions together works except for the fact that the capture groups are wrong. I tried switching `(\\-\\n)?` to `(?:\\-\\n)`, but then failed to match anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean sth like this `var newDoc = doc.replace(RegExp("\\b" + mask + "\\b", 'ig'), '<stuff>$&</stuff>')` ?

Comment: It looks like that does the trick! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly wanting a word-boundary `\b`. You can also shorten your code to this two-line snippet:

```js
var text = 'This is sand, and dand rand,\nand something else a-\nn-\nd dand';
var words = 'and dand'
console.log(text.replace(RegExp('\\b' + words.replace(/\B|(\S)\b/g, '$1(?:-\\n)?').replace(/\s/g, '\\s') + '\\b', 'ig'), '<stuff>$&</stuff>'))
```